# firefox multiple firing multiple javascript hover events

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, hover, mouseover

I am trying to mimic the "Our Numbers" animation from this page:

http://www.inspiro-media.com/Surreal/

(scroll to about 40% down the page to see the effect)

I've made decent progress, but I'm noticing that when I test it in Firefox the hover event fires multiple times when I hover over the circles. I can even get it to bounce in and out infinitely if I leave my mouse in the right spot.

Safari and Chrome seem to work fine (haven't tested in IE).

How can I fix this issue?

```
    <html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.circle {
    background: #2b94c8;
    border-radius: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.stat {
    position:relative;
    height:150px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
}
.wide {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100px;
    background:#CCC;
}
.num {
    font-size: 32px;
    line-height: 150px;
}
.fact {
    font-size: 0px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin-top: -85px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.circle').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).css('z-index','10');
                $(this).animate({
                    height: '+=100',
                    width: '+=100', marginLeft: '-=50',  marginTop: '-=50',
                    lineHeight: '250px'
                }, 200);
                $(this).children( ".num").animate({
                    fontSize: '70px', marginTop: '+=35'
                }, 200);
                $(this).children( ".fact").animate({
                    fontSize: '18px' , marginTop: '+=40'
                }, 300);
            },
            function(){
                $(this).css('z-index','1');
                $(this).children( ".num").animate({
                    fontSize: '32px', marginTop: '-=35'
                }, 200);
                $(this).children( ".fact").animate({
                    fontSize: '0px', marginTop: '-=25'
                }, 300);
                $(this).animate({
                    height: '-=100',
                    width: '-=100', marginLeft: '+=50', marginTop: '+=50',
                    lineHeight: '150px'
                }, 200);
                $(this).children( ".fact").animate({
                    marginTop: '-=15'
                }, 300);
            });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wide">
        <div class="stat">
            <div class="circle">
              <div class="num">2,450</div>
              <div class="fact">Traffic jams fixed</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wide">
      <div class="stat">
            <div class="circle">
              <div class="num">850</div>
              <div class="fact">Traffic jams fixed</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wide">
      <div class="stat">
            <div class="circle">
              <div class="num">22</div>
              <div class="fact">Traffic jams fixed</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is essentially just [mouseEnter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseLeave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/), have you considered trying it with those separately first?

Comment: You could break the hovers into named functions. That way you could unbind the event handler with off() from the mouseover until the animation finishes.  In the animate's success method you could rebind the function to the mouseover

Comment: I actually did try putting them in separate events and binding them to mouseEnter() and mouseLeave() but it did the same thing. One thing I noticed about the Surreal link is that they seem to be binding the event to an outer div or maybe even a dummy div. I couldn't get it to work that way, though.